# Changing/looping text in label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label, uilabel

I want to make my label change text every 5 seconds from `rLabel.text = "\(update) free trial"` wait for another 5 second then change it `rLabel.text = "upgrade now!"` ~ on repeat.

```
rLabel.text = "\(update) free trial"
    if daysLeft <= 5 {
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timer.fire()
        }
    } else {
        rLabel.text = "\(update) free trial"
    }
@objc func update() {
    rLabel.text = "upgrade now!"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the problem is? Your code shown above should, as far as I can tell, work just fine.

Comment: There's an issue with your question. Where does seconds come from? Where is update set in? Your question is incomplete without these two information

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a boolean to switch the text every 5 sec

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

var isShowingText1 = false
@objc func updateText(){
    rLabel.text = isShowingText1 ? "Text 2" : "Text 1"
    isShowingText1 = !isShowingText1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of current text by having `index` property. Also you can use `Timer` with `block` closure and you can avoid having Obj-C-ish `#selector`

```
var index = 0 {
    didSet {
        if index > 1 { index = 0 }
    }
}

var text: String {
    return ["\(update) free trial", "upgrade now!"][index]
}

func foo() {
    rLabel.text = text
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
        self.index += 1
        self.rLabel.text = self.text
    }
}
```